SQL Rank Scores
Write a SQL query to rank scores. If there is a tie between two scores, both
should have the same ranking. Note that after a tie, the next ranking number
should be the next consecutive integer value. In other words, there should be no
"holes" between ranks.
+----+-------+
| Id | Score |
+----+-------+
| 1 | 3.50 |
| 2 | 3.65 |
| 3 | 4.00 |
| 4 | 3.85 |
| 5 | 4.00 |
| 6 | 3.65 |
+----+-------+

For example, given the above Scores table, your query should generate the
following report (order by highest score):
+-------+------+
| Score | Rank |
+-------+------+
| 4.00 | 1 |
| 4.00 | 1 |
| 3.85 | 2 |
| 3.65 | 3 |
| 3.65 | 3 |
| 3.50 | 4 |
+-------+------+

One of the given answers:
select
 Score, @rank := @rank + (@prev <> (@prev := Score)) as Rank
from
 Scores, (select @rank := 0, @prev := -1) as a
order by Score desc;

However, this makes no sense to me unless the table was ordered by Score before SQL processed row by row. I've asked ChatGPT and Copilot numerous times, but ChatGPT shows the row by row calculation with the data already ordered, but ordering should be at the end only  for visualization purposes.
This is what I was saying before ChatGPT does, it doesn't process 3.50 first the first row in the table, it orders it first, but the problem is I don't understand it when it is not ordered first: Let's run the query step by step on the Scores table:
Step 1: Initialization
Initialize user-defined variables @rank and @prev with initial values of 0 and -1, respectively.
Step 2: Process Each Row
Start with the first row in the table.
Row 1: Score = 4.00
@prev is initially -1.
@rank is initially 0.
Calculate @prev <> (@prev := Score). Since -1 is not equal to 4.00, this evaluates to TRUE.
Increment @rank by 1 since TRUE is equivalent to 1. Now @rank becomes 1.
Result for this row: (Score = 4.00, Rank = 1).
My question is, does this sql answer make sense to you without ordering it first? The query does not order it first from what I can tell, but it only makes sense to me when the query runs row by row after the data is ordered (like ChatGPT seems to do but that is kinda irrelevant.)

Use DENSE_RANK() function.

My question is, does this sql answer make sense to you without ordering it first? No, if you tell about "sort then execute query". Yes, if your mean that ORDER BY must be present in the query.

Hi Akina, ORDER BY is for at the end for visualization purposes not for the calculation, but I am saying this query makes sense to me when the data is ordered DESC before the query executes row by row.

As the answerer below has mentioned using other words, Generative AI is not a serious programming resource and shouldn't be used on its own as such, at least not in any current publicly-available iteration. It often gives outdated, inaccurate, or outright non-working code and suggestions and is not a replacement for fully understanding your tech stack and the associated documentation. It does not possess any intrinsic ability to fully conceptualize and understand the output it generates, despite said outputs appearing very convincing in nature.

@Akina Am I right though? does this query not work without ordering first (order by is last in the query I know but for visualization purposes). I am trying to understand if my understanding of the query I provided is right rather than use another method.

When SELECT (or UPDATE) query contains ORDER BY clause and the (user-defined or local) variables are used in the output list expressions then the rows are processed strctly in specified ordering. Rather than in other clauses and subqueries where the evaluation order is unpredictable.

I recommend you use the DENSE_RANK() window function instead, assuming you are using MySQL 8.0 or later.
select
 Score, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score DESC) AS drank
from
 Scores
order by Score desc;

To answer your question, the rows are in fact ordered before the variable-assignment is evaluated in the select-list.
Here's a demonstration:
I make a table that has a set of characters in random order:
mysql> select * from mytable;
+------+
| c    |
+------+
| a    |
| x    |
| t    |
| h    |
| d    |
+------+

Now I concatenate them, and this preserves the order they are stored in the table (i.e. the order of the clustered index):
mysql> set @str='';
mysql> select @str := concat(@str, c) from mytable;
+-------------------------+
| @str := concat(@str, c) |
+-------------------------+
| a                       |
| ax                      |
| axt                     |
| axth                    |
| axthd                   |
+-------------------------+

Now I try to concatenate the characters again, but using ORDER BY to make the rows process in a particular order:
mysql> set @str='';
mysql> select @str := concat(@str, c) from mytable order by c;
+-------------------------+
| @str := concat(@str, c) |
+-------------------------+
| a                       |
| ad                      |
| adh                     |
| adht                    |
| adhtx                   |
+-------------------------+

This demonstrates that ORDER BY is not just a display-only operation after all select-list has been evaluated.
MySQL now discourages using := to set values of user-defined variables in the select-list, and this feature may be removed in a future version of MySQL. See the manual for reasons why.

thank you Bill, I appreciate your answer, but can you please let me know if my understanding of the query I provided is right as in it only actually makes sense if the table is ordered before the query is executed? I will decide if I choose as an answer later once I figure this out.

I believe my demo above proves that this is not the case.

I also tested your example from your post, and it does rank the scores properly. Did you test it?

If I go line by line: Score = 3.50
@prev is init -1
@rank is init 0
Calc @prev <> (@prev := Score). Since -1 is <> to 3.50, this evaluates to TRUE
Increment @rank by 1 since TRUE is equivalent to 1. Now @rank = 1
Result for row: (Score = 3.50, Rank = 1)
Row 2: Score = 3.65
@prev is now 3.50
@rank is now 1
Calc @prev <> (@prev := Score). Since 3.50 is <> to 3.65, this evaluates to TRUE
Increment @rank by 1. Now @rank = 2
Result for row: (Score = 3.65, Rank = 2)
Row 3: Score = 4.00

@prev is now 3.65
@rank is now 2
Calc @prev <> (@prev := Score). Since 3.65 is <> to 4.00, this evaluates to TRUE
Increment @rank by 1. Now @rank = 3
Result for row: (Score = 4.00, Rank = 3)          ** But 4 should be rank 1 **

I'm not sure how I can help you. Test the query. Don't imagine how it works. Test it.
